# Merging multiple series based on one label in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a panel that makes use of the following promql query to monitor the ram usage of IIS Application Pools on a server:

```
windows_process_working_set_bytes{process=~"w3wp_.*", instance="Server"}
```

This returns the following results: (pseudo)

| Time | process | process_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-09 01:00 | w3wp_foobar | 1000 | 500000 |
| 2022-11-09 01:15 | w3wp_foobar | 1000 | 100000 |
| 2022-11-09 01:30 | w3wp_spam_ham_eggs | 1200 | 700000 |
| 2022-11-09 01:45 | w3wp_foobar | 1000 | 300000 |
| 2022-11-09 02:00 | w3wp_foobar | 1000 | 500000 |
| 2022-11-09 02:15 | w3wp_foobar | 1500 | 300000 |
| 2022-11-09 02:30 | w3wp_spam_ham_eggs | 1200 | 600000 |
| 2022-11-09 02:45 | w3wp_foobar | 1500 | 700000 |

While this shows only two processes, it returns three series, because the `process_id` of `w3wp_foobar` changed. How can I completely omit `process_id` so that I only have two series? This change occurs when the application pool restarts. Because this panel tracks 20+ application pools, having multiple series for the same pool clouds the legend with double entries.

I have already tried the merge transformation, but this merges everything into a single series, which doesn't work for me. Since this is a single metric, I can't perform a join either. (as far as I'm aware)

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate it on the Prometheus level, e.g. `max`:

```
max(
  windows_process_working_set_bytes{process=~"w3wp_.*", instance="Server"}
) by (process)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try also the following PromQL:

```
max without (process_id) (windows_process_working_set_bytes{process=~"w3wp_.*", instance="Server"})
```